# R rolling subtraction vectorized alternative to a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

```
Leaves<- c(2,4,6,7,8,10,11,15)
ax<- c(2,1,1,2,3,1,1,1)
bx <- c(0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1) 
mydata<- data.frame(Leaves, ax, bx)
Sx<- c()
Sx[1] <- sum(x$ax)
for(i in 2:length(mydata$Leaves)){     
  Sx[i] <- Sx[i-1] - mydata$ax[i-1]
}
```

What's going on here is I want the first value for the Sx column to be the sum of the ax column. The second value of Sx should be Sx[1]-ax[1], the third value of Sx should be Sx[2]-ax[2, and so on.

This code works right now but it's a for-loop. Does anyone know of a way to make a vectorized alternative to this for loop? I've looked a lot into Dplyr lag and data.table shift functions but I'm not sure how to get those to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorized way would be  :

```
mydata$Sx <- sum(mydata$ax) - cumsum(mydata$ax) + mydata$ax
mydata

#  Leaves ax bx Sx
#1      2  2  0 12
#2      4  1  0 10
#3      6  1  0  9
#4      7  2  0  8
#5      8  3  2  6
#6     10  1  0  3
#7     11  1  0  2
#8     15  1  1  1
```

Comment: You made it look easy thank you very much!